# Angular 8 mat video player problem with progress bar

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-material, angular8

i have problem with mat-video module into my project. 
I'm trying to display a video and that works correct but a video progress bar takes 20% of full video width and i can't set full width.

Code:

HTML:

```
<mat-video #vid [ngClass]="ngclass" [src]="src" [title]="title" [autoplay]="autoplay" [preload]="preload"
  [loop]="loop" [fullscreen]="fullscreen" [download]="download" [quality]="quality" [keyboard]="keyboard"
  [color]="color" [spinner]="spinner" [poster]="poster" [overlay]="overlay" [(muted)]="muted"
  [showFrameByFrame]="showFrameByFrame" [(time)]="currentTime">
</mat-video>
```

TS:

```
ngclass = 'mat-video-responsive';
src = '../assets/video/nature.mp4';
title = 'Some title';
width = 600;
height = 337.5;
currentTime = 0;
autoplay = false;
preload = true;
loop = false;
quality = true;
download = false;
fullscreen = true;
showFrameByFrame = false;
keyboard = true;
color = 'primary';
spinner = 'spin';
poster = '';
overlay = null;
muted = false;
```

Effect:
[image]

I did everything as in the guide: [mat-video npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-video)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. This solved my problem:

```
:host::ng-deep .progress{
  background-color: unset !important;
}

:host::ng-deep mat-seek-progress-control{
  width: 100%;
}
```